# Counting rows per record

Tags: list

I'm trying count the total number of invoices where record is concurent.

Comment: Can you clarify what 1,2,3,4,10,11,34 would output ?

Is it the max (4) or 6 (4+2) ? Or something else ?

Or it would give 2 lines one with 4 and one with 2 ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding your question. However, if Invoice Numbers are consecutive like 100, 102, 103, 104, 105 then thats a sum of 5 invoices. If invoices were like 100, 102, 103, 104, 105, 107, thats still a sum of 5 invoices since 107 breaks the consecutive numbers

Comment: Ok it was about stopping and then having new invoices later.

Do you want the output to count invoices for each vendor id or the sum of each invoices no matter what ?

Comment: I need to count the number of invoices that have consecutive Invoice IDs. Once I have the count, I need to sum it for each Vendor ID and display the Vendor ID, Name and the total count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my commented solution.
It does recreate a panda frame, you need to pass the rows name for the id and the one on which we count the invoicing.

```
def count_consecutive_invoice(table, invoice_row_name, id_row_name):
  invoiced_table = {} # the output

  for row in table:
    if row != invoice_row_name:
      invoiced_table[row] = []
  invoiced_table['Cont of Consecutive Invoices'] = []

  streak = False # keep track of streaking invoices cause on first invoice we need to add 2, not 1

  for line in range(len(table[invoice_row_name]) - 1):
    id = table[id_row_name][line]

    if not id in invoiced_table[id_row_name]:
      for row in table:
        if row != invoice_row_name:
          invoiced_table[row].append(table[row][line])
      invoiced_table['Cont of Consecutive Invoices'].append(0)

    

    if id == table[id_row_name][line+1]: #check the vendor id so if you get the invoicing for each
      if table[invoice_row_name][line]+1 == table[invoice_row_name][line+1]: # check the actual invoicing

        itable_line = invoiced_table[id_row_name].index(id)
        
        invoiced_table['Cont of Consecutive Invoices'][itable_line] += 1 + int(not streak) #otherwise we add 1 or 2 depending on the streak status
        
        streak = True
        continue
    streak = False

  return invoiced_table

invoiced = count_consecutive_invoice(df, "Invoice ID", "Vendor ID")
print(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(invoiced))
```

Comment: I'm having some trouble testing this with my data set and I understand you did it based on a general table. My data set is in excel and the Invoice is a column. In the def function where you have "def count_consecutive_invoice(table)", would the argument be "def count_consecutive_invoice(df, Invoice):" ? Note: I'm a beginner. I may not be understanding the arguments set in def.

Comment: There are no needs for those parameters, I hard coded the access to the different row with the input you gave.
Have you any error ?

Comment: I edited the solution so you can call the function with your names

Comment: I was able to call in my function with your code. However, I'm getting a count of 7 instead of 8.

Comment: Check your input you have 100,102,103,104 so 100 and 102 are note invoiced so the result is 4+3 i think !

Comment: You're right, I was overlooking my own example. Code seems to work now

Answer (score 2):

I am unsure about what it is you exactly want. I'm going to base my expectations on your code.

There are a three errors in the code:

1. Function arguments should a variable name.

```
def count_consecutive_invoice (df, invoiceNumber):
    retlist = []
    
    for i in range(len(df[InvoiceNumber]) - 1):
```

Notice the removal of quotes around `invoiceNumber`. You set, what it's equal to later, when calling the function.

2. You are trying to call the function instead of accessing a variable:

```
if count_consecutive_invoice[i] + 1 == count_consecutive_invoice[i  
+ 1]:
```

Should be

```
if df[InvoiceNumber][i] + 1 == df[InvoiceNumber][i + 1]:
```

3. You need to declare all variables, including count.
   To do this, just add `count = 1` after `retlist = []`.

This code should work:

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'MYPath\Book1.xlsx')

def count_consecutive_invoice (df, invoiceNumber):
    retlist = []

    count = 1
    
    for i in range(len(df[ivoiceNumber]) - 1):
        # Check if the next number is consecutive
        if df[invoiceNumber][i] + 1 == df[invoiceNumber][i+1]:
            count += 1
        elif count > 1:
            # If it is not and count > 1 append the count and restart counting
            retlist.append(count)
            count = 1
    # Since we stopped the loop one early append the last count
    retlist.append(count)
    return retlist

output = count_consecutive_invoice(df, 'Invoice Number')
print(output)
```

output:

```
[4]
```

Comment: I appreciate the assistance with editing my code which I have used. However, the results are not what i'm looking for. I updated my original post and hope it clarifies. I'm only looking to count the number of invoices where the invoice ID is consecutive.

Comment: @Meowzz this posts author made a small mistake which I corrected - should work now.

Comment: I updated my example and explanation. Hope its clearer.